# I am using nodemailer but I got an error about ETIMEDOUT without any services

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, error-handling, nodemailer

I want to use nodemailer to send the email to the users but I caught en error about ETIMEDOUT but I am not sure what is going on inside the nodemailer module,

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const sendEmail = async (options) => {
  // 1-) Create a transporter
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.EMAIL_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
    },
  });
  // 2-) Define the email options
  const mailOptions = {
    from: 'Ogun AÇIĞ <MyEmail> ',
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    text: options.message,
    //html
  };

  //3-) Actually send the email
  await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

> I have used the **EMAIL_HOST,EMAIL_PORT,EMAIL_USERNAME and EMAIL_PASSWORD** with my Mailtrap account credentials, if I get the concept of the subject, the message will be send to that Mailtrap account for now. I will change the properties **MAIL_HOST,MAIL_PORT,EMAIL USERNAME and EMAIL PASSWORD** with information of real user but I need to send a message first.

```
 try {
    await sendEmail({
      email: user.email,
      subject: 'Your password reset token (vaild for 10 minute)',
      message,
    });

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'succes',
      message: 'Token sent to email',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    user.passwordResetExpires = undefined;
    user.passwordResetToken = undefined;
    await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
    return next(
      new AppError(error.message, 500);
    );
  }
```

This is where I got this error. I will be appreciative for your help if you warn me about my mistake.